# Consume JSON web service from Node/Express request?

Tags: javascript, http, node.js, express

I have the following route:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

I would like to call the following web service: http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last/results and tell it to return JSON.

I have tried something like this in the index request but it errors:

```
var options = {
  host: 'ergast.com',
  port: 80,
  path:'/api/f1/current/last/results.json'
};

http.get(options, function(response) {
  response.setEncoding('utf-8');
  console.log("Got response: " + response.statusCode);
  var data = JSON.parse(response);
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
}).on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
```

I'm guessing I'm probably missing the point somewhere.

Thanks

Comment: [API](http://ergast.com/mrd/) -> Response Formats -> JSONP

Comment: You're recommending JSONP? I've updated my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be simple :) I recommend you using the request module (npm install request, or just add it to your packages.json file).

Then you can do the following:

```
var request = require("request");
request.get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last/results.json", function (err, res, body) {
    if (!err) {
        var resultsObj = JSON.parse(body);
        //Just an example of how to access properties:
        console.log(resultsObj.MRData);
    }
});
```

I see the suggestion about using JSONP instead of just going straight for the JSON API.

JSONP's reason for existing is for cross-domain APIs on the browser. Since you're running this on the server, the cross-domain restrictions are not an issue and thus JSONP is not required. Go ahead and do as you wish anyway!

EDIT: I ain't sure about why you don't try this. If it is for error management, I have updated the code with error management now.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and JSONP clarification

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'request'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)

Comment: It was installed like so sudo npm install -g request

Comment: You should do a local install: npm install request. You won't need to use sudo and you will be able to control the version for your project instead of invading other applications that might intent to use the module in the future. It is highly recommended that you use a packages.json file for all of this. Personally, I love this cheatsheet http://package.json.jit.su/ Then you can just do "npm install -d". But a "npm install request" should suffice.

Comment: i thought so too but I had to do it that way for nodemon so i assume this would be the same

Comment: so i uninstalled it globally, installed it locally and all works fine. Thanks. I dont get why it wasnt working the other way though

Comment: npm global installations are for things that expose themselves to the command line (not just node). For example, express has an "express" command, forever, typescript (tsc for compiling into js files). Other than those cases, always go with local installations.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument you supplied to `http.get` isn't correct.  See the [node.js docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) regarding this function.  Instead of passing in `options` just pass in the full URL as a string, e.g.

```
http.get('http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last/results', function(res) {
...
```

EDIT: After your edit, the `options` argument *still* isn't correct.  If you want to use an options dictionary, specify this:

```
{ host: 'ergast.com', port: 80, path: '/api/f1/current/last/results' }
```

Comment: Thanks that made a difference however the JSON.stringify fails

Comment: Because you should be using JSON.parse

Comment: so console.log(JSON.parse(response));

Comment: It throws an error though: undefined:1
[object Object]
 ^
Got response: 200
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
    at ClientRequest.exports.index.res.render.title (/Users/Jon/Documents/Github/NodeF1/routes/index.js:14:31)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:193:14)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:93:17)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1461:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:111:23)
    at Socket.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1366:20)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:403:27)

Comment: You can use my solution. Or you can just add .json at the end of the path so that it actually returns the body in json format :P