# Need some help while calling webservice using node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am taking help from this example .
[Consume JSON web service from Node/Express request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716439/consume-json-web-service-from-node-express-request)
I create a js file in my directory C:/programfile/nodejs/
Inside that I write this code

```
var request = require("request");
request.get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last/results.json", function (err, res, body) {
    if (!err) {
        var resultsObj = JSON.parse(body);
        //Just an example of how to access properties:
        console.log(resultsObj.MRData);
    }
});
```

the from command promt I run this script

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\nksharma.Q3TECH>cd..

C:\Documents and Settings>cd..

C:\>cd "Program Files"

C:\Program Files>cd nodejs

C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sane defaults.

See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg> --save` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
name: (nodejs)
version: (0.0.0)
description:
git repository:
keywords:
author:
license: (BSD-2-Clause)
About to write to C:\Program Files\nodejs\package.json:

{
  "name": "nodejs",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "a.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "npm": "~1.3.17",
    "jsonraver": "~0.5.0",
    "request": "~2.29.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause"
}


Is this ok? (yes)

C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install request --save
npm WARN package.json nodejs@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json nodejs@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json nodejs@0.0.0 No README data
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-agent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tough-cookie
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tunnel-agent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/form-data
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/oauth-sign
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http-signature
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hawk
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-agent
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tough-cookie
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tunnel-agent
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/form-data
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/oauth-sign
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-signature
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hawk
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/asn1/0.1.11
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/assert-plus/0.1.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ctype/0.5.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/punycode
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/assert-plus/0.1.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/asn1/0.1.11
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ctype/0.5.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/punycode
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
request@2.29.0 node_modules\request
├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
├── forever-agent@0.5.0
├── tunnel-agent@0.3.0
├── qs@0.6.6
├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
├── aws-sign2@0.5.0
├── mime@1.2.11
├── node-uuid@1.4.1
├── tough-cookie@0.9.15 (punycode@1.2.3)
├── hawk@1.0.0 (cryptiles@0.2.2, boom@0.4.2, sntp@0.2.4, hoek@0.9.1)
├── http-signature@0.10.0 (assert-plus@0.1.2, asn1@0.1.11, ctype@0.5.2)
└── form-data@0.1.2 (async@0.2.9, combined-stream@0.0.4)

C:\Program Files\nodejs>
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: I want to call web service using NODe.js

Comment: That's what you want, but what is the problem you're having? You've not added any information on how/if you're actually starting node (a'la "node test.js") and what - if not correct - your outcome and expected outcome is.

Comment: I am getting error my package.json having error

Comment: can you please give some steps how to start i am frustrated from this problem

Comment: @user2648752 sorry to say this, but this isn't actually a problem. You  are facing a problem because you haven't even learned how to start a node.js program, and you expect us to teach it to you. Post questions on this website when you actually understand node.js properly and you are facing a real issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have just initialized the node.js environment, now you need to actually **run** the program.

```
node json.js // whetever the file name that you saved the script with
```

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is a new concept when it comes to scripting in javascript.  It took me a while trying to understand it, even though after so much hours googling and studying tutorials until I came across to this site.  Very simple learning and finally got the light blub above my head.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/introduction-to-express

You then will see how your script above is not completed yet.  Hope that helps (took 30 minutes of my time - just follow through and copying n' pasting each process through the tutorial).